# Inversion sampling for a truncated normal distribution?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, random-generation

I'm a bit unsure how to approach this problem given that the normal CDF has no closed form solution.

> Let $f(x|\mu,\sigma,c)$ be a normal distribution left-truncated at
>   $c$, so that
>   $$f(x|\mu,\sigma,c)=\frac{\exp\left(-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)
>  \right)}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma(1-\Phi((c-\mu)/\sigma))}\mathbb{1}(x\geq
>  c).$$ Design an algorithm based on CDF inversion to draw samples from
>   the above truncated normal distribution.

I'm unsure how I'm supposed to make use of CDF inversion if there's no closed form expression for $\Phi^{-1}(\cdot)$. Nevertheless, if I integrate the above PDF, I get

$$F(x)=\frac{\Phi \left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \right)-\Phi \left(\frac{c-\mu}{\sigma} \right)}{1-\Phi \left(\frac{c-\mu}{\sigma} \right) }$$

Which is then inverted to obtain

$$F^{-1}(y) = \mu+\sigma \Phi^{-1}\left\{y\left( 1-\Phi \left(\frac{c-\mu}{\sigma} \right) \right)+\Phi \left(\frac{c-\mu}{\sigma} \right)\right\}$$

So my questions are:

1. Am I right in my thinking that since no closed form expression of $\Phi^{-1}(\cdot)$ exists, an inversion-based algorithm has to make use of numerical approximations built into programs like R? As opposed to an exact expression
2. For the above formula, do I have to do anything special to 'deal' with the truncation? Or can I simply generate a $u \sim U[0,1]$ like normal, and invert it using the above formula?

Thanks!

Comment: If you did it right, it should reduce to truncating the uniform (which remains uniform and simply reduces its range) and then using an untruncated inverse Gaussian transform of that.

Comment: In what sense does "no closed form expression of $\Phi^{-1}$ exist"? It seems to me that "$\Phi^{-1}$" works perfectly well as a closed, finite expression because computing it is no more problematic than, say computing values of $\exp,$ $\log,$ or other elementary functions and its analytical properties are well understood. Indeed, a standard definition of $\exp$ sets $\phi(t)=\log(t)=\int_1^t\frac{dx}{x}$ and then defines $\exp$ as $\phi^{-1}.$ In both cases integrals are inverted; the only difference is in the former case the integrand is $\exp(-x^2/2)$ and in the latter it is $1/x.$